# Cannot be able to write table with header to s3 path in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following dataset:

```
+-------------------+-------+------------+                                      
|test_control_status|user_id|loyalty_type|
+-------------------+-------+------------+
|TEST               |920799 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |922428 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |2063890|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2344814|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2355426|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2618707|loyalty     |
+-------------------+-------+------------+
```

I used following script for writing the above table to `s3` path:

```
df.write.option("header","true").mode("overwrite").csv("<s3: path>")
```

But, when trying to read table for further operation the table looks like:

```
+-------------------+-------+------------+                                      
|                _c0|    _c1|         _c2|
+-------------------+-------+------------+
|test_control_status|user_id|loyalty_type|
|TEST               |920799 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |922428 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |2063890|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2344814|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2355426|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2618707|loyalty     |
+-------------------+-------+------------+
```

Where as i want the table to be like:

```
+-------------------+-------+------------+                                      
|test_control_status|user_id|loyalty_type|
+-------------------+-------+------------+
|TEST               |920799 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |922428 |loyalty     |
|TEST               |2063890|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2344814|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2355426|loyalty     |
|TEST               |2618707|loyalty     |
+-------------------+-------+------------+
```

I tried writing file in `parquet` format then it worked, but i want to write file in `.csv` format only.
Any kind of help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: in your spark.read.csv() line, make sure set the option `header=True`. the default is None(False).

Comment: yes it worked, i wasn't reading with the "header" "true"

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
sqlContext.read.csv("s3:///file_path", header = True)
```